# remove string using strtr

Tags: php, preg-replace, strtr

say it if i want to remove a word like this: `',40,15,550);context2.fillText('MY_TEXT_HERE',40,20,550);context2.fillText('`

so, i want to remove `',40,15,550);context2.fillText('` and `',40,20,550);context2.fillText('`

if using standart strtr is we need to create 2 condition like

```
$lyrics = ($_POST['utamapkanji']);
$replacements = [
            "',40,15,550);context2.fillText('" => " ",
            "',40,20,550);context2.fillText('" => " ",
            ];
            $result = strtr($lyrics , $replacements);
            ?>
```

result will be `MY_TEXT_HERE`.

what i want to do is, remove a word that begin `',40` and ended with `fillText('` so, by doing this i only need to make 1 condition to remove it.

Comment: sounds like a job for http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this replacement:

```
$result = preg_replace("(\',40[^\']*\')", '', $lyrics);
```

Comment: can u please explain what that mean.

Comment: Yes, I was sleeping. This expression takes first _',40_ followed by everything whih is not an apostrophe _[^\']*_ and also takes the next apostrophe _'_.